# Extracting Specific Columns of CSV Data into a New File

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a project in Python where I need to extract specific columns of data from a large CSV file and write it to a new file.

I'm currently using the pandas library to read the CSV and select the columns, but it's taking a long time to process the file. Are there any ways to optimize this process and make it run faster?

Comment: Do a web search for the csv library that comes with Python. Maybe that's faster. Try it, we don't have your huge file, so we cannot compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `usecols` parameter of [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is what you are looking for?

Example: https://www.statology.org/pandas-read_csv-usecols/